# Handling concurrent reads?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I'm new to concurrent programming and I have a specific situation in mind that I'd like some input on.  If I have a variable that I will be accessing from multiple threads but only to read the value (the only reason it's wouldn't be a constant is because I'd need to set it at runtime), do I need a mutex for it? Or do you only need to worry about race conditions when there are also writes going out to a shared resource?

Comment: I was going to say you should always worry about race conditions, but that isn't very helpful. Instead I'd like to know: Do you "set it at runtime" before launching the threads, or afterwards?

Comment: Relevant, timely blog post by Eric Lippert: [Can I skip the lock when reading an integer?](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/) Of course there are nuances, but TLDR: Use the lock; future maintainers will thank you more for a lack of cryptic bugs from races than infinitesimal time savings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the value *before* you start up the threads, you do not need a mutex.
If you set the value *after* you start up the threads, you will need a mutex to ensure they all the threads read the same value.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was wondering.  However, based on some other responses, I think I would still use a mutex just to avoid any confusion down the road

Answer (score 2):

Logically,if you are only reading a shared data then you may not need to use mutex.But,in case of large programmes you must use it to avoid confusions.

Comment: If the value is only being read once multiple threads are started, there's no need for any sort of synchonization. It doesn't make any difference at all how 'large' the program is.

Comment: It does make a difference. :)

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what language and machine architecture you're talking about and what "reading the variable" means in that language. When "reading the variable" translates into only reading from memory at the machine-level, concurrent reads are in themselves generally safe. You need to be sure, of course, that nothing else in your program translates into writing to those same memory areas.

Many mainstream languages (Java, C#, C, C++) gives only very weak guarantees about how your program translates into memory accesses. At the same time, the guarantees you get tend to take the form of very complex rules, say, about which sequences of statements may be re-ordered when. To avoid introducing really difficult to find bugs, it's a very often better to require the synchronisation properties you need in as un-subtle and concrete a form as possible, that is, use mutexes.